# Overridden GetVaryByCustomString method being called only on first request to a page

Tags: asp.net, outputcache, c1-cms

I have the following question regarding outputcache work in either ASP.Net or Composite C1 CMS (don't know where's the problem):

I need to vary cache by cookie named "City". In Global.asax I've overridden the GetVaryByCustomString method.

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)
{
   var result = ApplicationLevelEventHandlers.GetVaryByCustomString(context, custom);

   if (result == null) {
      return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, custom);
   }

   HttpCookie cookie = context.Request.Cookies["City"];
   string additionalVary = "";
   if (cookie != null)
      additionalVary = cookie.Value;
   else
      additionalVary = "Москва";

   return String.Concat(result, additionalVary);
}
```

And the problem is: the breakpoint of my overridden GetVaryByCustomString method is being hit only on the first request to a page, but isn't being hit on next requests until the cache actually expires (60 seconds in my case). 
While the cookie might have been changed on the client side during that 60 seconds - the page is simply taken from the cache.

Where am I wrong? 
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**
I was finally able to make outputcache vary by cookie by the following modifications in the CacheProfile settings:

```
<outputCacheProfiles>
   <add name="C1Page" duration="60" varyByCustom="C1Page" varyByParam="*" varyByHeader="Cookie" location="Server" />
</outputCacheProfiles>
```

In this case the method GetVaryByCustomString is being hit on each request, but there's no need in it: these settings make the cache vary by every cookie might be set on the website. Of course it is not a desired behavior - that's why I'm continuing the investigation.

What is even more funny - these 2 parameters (varyByHeader="Cookie" and location="Server") work only together, disabling one of them make the things look exactly as before - outputcache not varying.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a break point to Application_BeginRequest, it could be that browser isn't making a request but rather showing a cached page.

Comment: Tried in the EndRequest - the breakpoint is being hit on every request.